# Can't grant myself permissions to use the rm command

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, osx, sudo

I have a user account on my machine:

```
$ (whoami)
foo_user
```

I've updated by `/etc/sudoers` file to grant myself permissions to use the `rm` command:

```
User_Alias      OPERATORS = foo_user
Cmnd_Alias      RM = /bin/rm
OPERATORS       ALL = RM
OPERATORS       ]ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

However, when I try to run rm on a directory, I get a permissions denied error:

```
rm: /root-directory: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide the exact command you are running?

Comment: You do do `sudo rm`, not just `rm`, do you?

Comment: What is the meaning of the `]` in `OPERATORS       ]ALL = (ALL) ALL`? And are you using `ubuntu` or `osx`?

Comment: Did you use `visudo` to edit _and syntax check_ the `sudoers` file?

Comment: Why `(whoami)` with brackets instead of just `whoami`?

Comment: Please consider editing you question to show the exact command that you are using, the exact lines from your `sudoers` file and also mention the operating system that you are using.  Currently, you don't show a command, the `sudoers` file has what looks like a typo in it, and you have tagged your question with both [tag:osx] and [tag:ubuntu].

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be doing is to allow a bunch of operators to use certain commands... Therefore do a `visudo` and add:

```
 Cmnd_Alias      CMD_OPERATOR=/bin/rm *
```

then add the group `operator` and allow that group to execute whatever is in the `CMD_OPERATOR`

```
 %operator       ALL=CMD_OPERATOR
```

Quit `visudo`, saving your changes and finally add `foo_user` to the group `operator`:

```
 usermod --append --groups operator foo_user
```

If you want to:

1. add more users to the operators group just:

   ```
    usermod --append --groups operator bar_user
   ```
2. Add any other commands to the operator group in the future, `visudo` again and separate them by a `,` as per below:

   ```
    Cmnd_Alias      CMD_OPERATOR=/bin/rm /media/*, /bin/umount /media/*
   ```

   In the above example operators are allowed to remove anything from the `/media/` mount and unmount it as well but they'll not be able to do silly stuff like `rm --recursive --force /etc` or `umount /home`

Comment: Obviously, If you have different kinds of operators, just define them separately with their own separate groups and commands.  E.G. `backup_operators`, `dev_operators`, ...